# Why isLockTaskPermitted flag is false

Tags: java, android, xml, locking, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to pin screen programmatically on Android L.
My app includes xml file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock/>
        <watch-login/>
        <disable-camera/>
        <disable-keyguard-features/>
        <encrypted-storage/>
        <expire-password/>
        <limit-password/>
        <reset-password/>
        <set-global-proxy/>
        <wipe-data/>
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

I installed app with proper lines in AndroidManifest file where I defined AdminReceiver. 
Everything worked fine a few weeks ago, but right now when I came back to this project - App ask me to confirm "Pin screen" popup everytime when app starts.

When I'm debugging I noticed weird behavior
`devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName)` is true
`devicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())` is true

but

`devicePolicyManager.isLockTaskPermitted(getPackageName())` is false

It doesn't matter if I set app as device owner using adb commend `dpm set-device-owner ...` or by pushing device_owner.xml file to /data/system/

My question is why app doesn't have permission to lock screen?

Answer (score 2):

For that you must call **setLockTaskPackages()**

You code should something like below.

**Your Activity should have**

```
ComponentName mAdminComponentName = DeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(this);
//where this will be your Activity

DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)
                getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(mAdminComponentName,new String[]{getPackageName()});
```

**DeviceAdminReceiver.java**

```
// Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
// 
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
// 
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
// 
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

package com.google.codelabs.cosu;

/**
 * Created by nyfuchs on 4/26/16.
 */

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 * Handles events related to the managed profile.
 */
public class DeviceAdminReceiver extends android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceAdminReceiver";

    /**
     * @param context The context of the application.
     * @return The component name of this component in the given context.
     */
    public static ComponentName getComponentName(Context context) {
        return new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), DeviceAdminReceiver.class);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.codelabs.cosu.DeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```